# Boost implementation for WaitForSingleObject-function

Tags: c++, boost

I am porting some Windows-specific code to boost.

I have the following function:

```
//m_hTesterPresent is a boost::thread*

unsigned long Class::fn_StopTesterPresentThread()
{
    // Check if tester-present is running, close it
    if (m_hTesterPresent)
    {
        m_bTesterPresentRunning = FALSE;

        WaitForSingleObject(m_hTesterPresent, INFINITE);        

        m_hTesterPresent->~thread();
        //CloseHandle(m_hTesterPresent);

        m_hTesterPresent = NULL;
    }

    return ACTION_SUCCESS;
}
```

How would I wait for the `m_hTesterPresent`-handled thread to finish, emulating the `WaitForSingleObject` Windows function?

Any help appreciated!

Comment: [boost::thread::join](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/doc/html/thread/thread_management.html#thread.thread_management.thread.join)?

Answer (score 1):

`m_hTesterPresent->~thread()` ? What do you think that does? We don't see all code, but that is almost certainly wrong.

The answer to your last sentence would be `boost::thread::join` but that `~thread` line suggests that you may be using `boost::thread` incorrectly, so that `join` may seem to fail.

Comment: Then how would I close the Handle to the Process correctly?

Comment: Handle to _process_? I'll assume you mean thread. That works like any other C++ object. `Class::~Class` will destroy it. You can clean up early by setting it to a non-running thread : `m_hTesterPresent = boost::thread{}`.

Comment: Yes I meant Thread - sorry.
So do I destroy it and then set it to a non-Running Thread or how would I do it.
I am still new to Threads and boost.

Comment: @RomanRoth: You can also check `std::thread`, which is substantially the same as `boost::thread`. The exact answer will depend a bit on what your `Class` does, and what its thread does. If the thread runs for the lifetime of the `Class`, the usual C++ ctor/dtor pattern works. You just need to make sure that your thread knows when to stop (no different from Windows threads), and to call `join` in `Class::~Class`.